# Memory increases with ViewController change in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, ios8

I am making an interactive kids book using Storyboard to lay out each of the 12 pages for my book. However, each time I switch View Controllers to go to another Storyboard, my memory increases by almost double each time. I keep getting memory warnings and crashes, and in the debug navigator, I see that the memory is jumping from ~36 to ~54 to ~95 until to gets to over 200.

I have tried using both segue transitions and programmatic transitions like this:

```
class page01VC:UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var kid: UIImageView!
let kidStanding = UIImage(named: "01_boyStanding")
let kidJumping = UIImage(named: "01_boyJumping")
var kidJump:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
var boyCounter: CGFloat = 0.0
var boyJumpTimer:NSTimer!

@IBOutlet var snowflakes: UIImageView!
let flakes = UIImage(named: "01_flakes")
var flakeTimer:NSTimer!

override func loadView() {

    super.loadView()

    flakeTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.008, target: self, selector: Selector("moveSnow"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    //NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(flakeTimer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)

    kidJump.frame = CGRectMake(140, 250, 338, 478)
    kidJump.addTarget(self, action: "kidJumpTimer:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)

    self.view.insertSubview(kidJump, aboveSubview:kid)

}

//Other functions I have made would be here
}
```

Does anyone know how I can prevent this memory build up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you removing the `NSTimer`s when the view controllers are no longer in use?

Comment: Nope, I'm not removing anything myself. Everywhere I look says that ARC will take care of things, but I guess it isn't!

Comment: I'm not really sure how to remove things after the views change.

Comment: See the discussion of NSTimer memory management in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_unusual_memory_management_situations As long as the timer is not invalidated, your view controller is retained, so your image is retained. So you are opening and retaining all these images. They are too big so you run out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Do you remove references to your timers in `viewDidDisappear`? Initiate your timers in `viewWillAppear` and remove them in `viewDidDisappear`. I think that the timers continue to exist even after the view is not visible.

Please see the [NSTimer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/) specifically “Scheduling Timers in Run Loops” (the bottom paragraph of that section) and the `invalidate` method.

Also check out [Performance Tips](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW1) in the App Programming Guide for iOS and [Resource Management in View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW1) in the View Controller Programming Guide for iOS.

Comment: I just tried this along with variations of invalidating and assigning the timer to nil, and I also tried using viewWillAppear and and viewWillDisappear, but I still have the huge memory increase. I also tried deleting the timers completely from every page, and there is still a memory increase.

Comment: This is how I am switching view controllers programmatically:            currentView.view.removeFromSuperview()
            currentView = myStory.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page\(pageNumber)") as UIViewController
            self.view.insertSubview(currentView.view, atIndex: 0)

Comment: Removing the views will not remove the view controller and `viewDidDisappear` won’t be called. You should use a [container view controller to do custom presentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) of sub-view-controllers. Most apps on iOS transition view controllers with a UINavigationController or UITabBarController. Your current way is fine for switching views, but not *view controllers*.